# Плавный скролл по якорям-ссылкам с изменением высоты фокуса работает, но не работает. В чем ошибка в коде?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Есть такой код, плавная прокрутка на сайте + небольшое изменение высоты фокуса при скролле "top - 80", потому-что шапка фиксированная и заголовок, на который идет фокус, не видно.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = $(this).attr("href");

$('html, body').stop().animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 80
    }, 500, function() {
        location.hash = target;
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

Работает, а точнее не работает это так. При скролле идет плавная прокрутка до нужного мне заголовка. Пока прокрутка не остановилась, то фокусится все как нужно, но как только доходит до нужной точки с учетом этих 80px, то резко возвращается в положение без учета этих 80px.
Если же повторно нажать на ту же ссылку-якорь, то он плавно прокрутится до нужно точки и останется на ней как и положено. Почему только не с первого раза?

Comment: Поместите в вопрос рабочий пример.

Comment: `location.hash = target;` - когда анимация кончилась, вы обновляете адрес, что приводит к скролированию страницы. Второй раз скролирования нет, так как не меняется адрес (он уже изменён при первом присвоении). См https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645202/can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-having-the-web-page-scroll

Comment: Спасибо, убрал, помогло.